# Add reactions to embed in a order

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I got these lines of code:

```
if (command === 'upcoming') {
  if (message.member.roles.find('name', 'Lúcifer')) {
    const change = args.join(' ');
    message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
    const upcomingEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor('#FFAA44')
      .setAuthor('Trench: Changelog and upcoming', `${client.user.avatarURL}`)
      .addField('Upcoming:',
        `${change}`)
      .setFooter('Powered by FullGaamer')
      .setTimestamp();

    message.channel.send(upcomingEmbed).then(embedMessage => {
      embedMessage.react('');
      embedMessage.react('');
    });
  } else {
    message.channel.send('Você não tem permissão para utilizar deste comando.');
  }
}
```

The  &  reactions get showed randomly, but I want them to always show up in this order!

I've tried using `await` before `embedMessage` and no success!

Comment: Please describe: A) What is the target behavior; B) What is the problem right now and C) What were your last steps to solve that problem. As of now there question in here…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async and await.

```
message.channel.send(upcomingEmbed).then(async embedMessage => {
    await embedMessage.react('');
    await embedMessage.react('');
});
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I was missing the async!